# How to combine multiple for-loop in Python from text file

Tags: python, file, for-loop

I tried to read some data from text file and print it multiple times as example below:

```
fruits.txt
apple
banana
orange


file = open(
    "D:/Python/fruits.txt", "r")

f = []
for line in file:
    f.append(line.strip())

file.close()

for fruits in f:
    print(f"Sam likes {fruits}")
print()
for fruits in f:
    print(f"James does't like {fruits}")
print()
for fruits in f:
    print(f"Bob likes {fruits}")
```

Is there any way to make my code cleaner other than above without repeating the for-loop for each person?
I want to print each person with the data inside a text file, then continue to the next person and so on.
I already searched for any solutions but still can't find the best answer. Hope somebody can help me. Thanks

Comment: This is more codereview.stackexchange.com, but not really. You want to do all of the first person, then the second, etc.... that's 3 loops. Nothing wrong with doing it this way.

Comment: You could do `with open("D:/Python/fruits.txt") as fileobj: f = [line.strip() for line in fileobj]`

Comment: @tdelaney, Thanks for the input. As suggested, I've replaced by using with statement now.

Answer (score 0):

```
names = ['Sam likes ', 'James doesn\'t like ', 'Bob likes ']

for name in names:
    for fruits in f:
        print(name + fruits)
```

Something like this should work.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this

```py
fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange']

persons = ['Sam', 'Bob', 'James']
personsLikesFruits = ['Sam', 'Bob']

for person in persons:
    print()
    does_like_fruits = person in personsLikesFruits
    
    for fruit in fruits:
        print(f"{person} {'likes' if does_like_fruits else 'doesnt like'} {fruit}")
```

Which prints the following

```py
Sam likes apple
Sam likes banana
Sam likes orange

Bob likes apple
Bob likes banana
Bob likes orange

James doesnt like apple
James doesnt like banana
James doesnt like orange
```

Also as mentioned by @tdelaney from the comment, you can open the file using [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) statement, so you don't have to `close` the file manually

```py
with open("D:/Python/fruits.txt") as file:
    fruits = [line.strip() for line in file]
```

**Edit**
Using [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) as mentioned by @chepner.

```py
import itertools

for p, f in itertools.product(persons, fruits):
    does_like_fruits = p in personsLikesFruits
    print(f"{p} {'likes' if does_like_fruits else 'doesnt like'} {f}")
```

Comment: You can hide one of the loops: `for p, f in itertools.product(persons, fruits): print(f'{p} likes {f}')`